# node js scheduler it definite time with agenda

Tags: node.js, scheduler

I am trying to create scheduler with a help of agenda module. I want to do something simple: to run some job every 30 min. For this one I can use agenda.every('30 minutes', 'my task') function. But how can I tell to agenda to do it exactly in 00 or in 30 minutes of every hour? Since I use for deployment heroku that reboots dynos from time to time I can't be sure that heroku won't move my scheduler from 30 minutes to 45 for example.

Comment: did you try using cron syntax ? like `0,30 * * * *` ?

Comment: it looks like good solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron package from npm also - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron.

It supports cron syntax. As a result you can write schedules like `0,30 * * * * *`.